# Ionic Gridview column issue in mobile site

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an issue in mobile device while showing row column grid view in ionic. the column 33 is taking width:33.33%. the grid are wrapping are as:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-33"></div>
  <div class="col col-33"></div>
  <div class="col col-33"></div>
<div>
```

it takes more space on the right side. how i can get rid from that.??

Comment: It might an error while copying here but the second column does not close the div properly. It should be `<div class="col col-33"></div>`. If you fix that it should work [fine](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwdGEX).

Comment: yes i was skipped while writting code here.. in the file i have put it right syntax. but the same problem occurs. its taking some extra space from the right hand side..